# Unable to receive snmp trap from a siemens device

Tags: net-snmp, snmptrapd

I have a siemens switch whose IP I have assigned as 192.168.0.1 I have installed the net-snmp snmaptrapd application on my ubuntu system whose IP is 192.168.0.2 and am trying to get the traps from the siemens device.

I see the traps being generated from siemens device on wireshark and ireasoning mibbrowser.But I do not get any traps received in the snmptrapd application which should log in /var/log/syslog. But when I send a snmptrap command(sudo snmptrap -v 1 -c public localhost SN-MSPS-SCX200-MIB::snMspsTrapPowerLine2Up localhost 2 0 '' IF-MIB::ifIndex i 1), I get the trap received log in the syslog.

Why doesn't the snmptrapd receive traps from the siemens device?

How to receive traps from the siemens device?

I have added these lines in snmptrapd.conf file

authCommunity log,execute,net public authCommunity log,execute,net private

[snmp] logOption sd

disableAuthorization yes ignoreAuthFailure yes

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.